Specflow: navigating and debugging steps in nuget package
I have created a nuget package containing steps which is then referenced on my test framework.
In term of discovery and execution it works all fine, but I am unable to navigate to the step definition from my feature file within the editor. Also at run time, I am unable to step into the step from the feature at run time making debugging very ineffective.
I suspected this is due to the code being compiled within the DLL, so I have enabled source link on the package, but I am still unable to navigate at editor time to the underlying code.
Has anyone managed to get a similar situation working?

Can you [edit] your question to include more information? We need a [repro], otherwise we can't help you. Do you see a .pdb file in your NuGet package?

And Visual Studio can be configured to not step into methods defined in other assemblies. I wonder if that is causing issues.
